# Pass function as parameter to integrate object using lambda

Tags: c++, math, syntax

For educational purposes

I have a function integrate which takes in a std::function as a parameter.

```
double calculus::integralSimple(std::function<double(double)> fn, double begin, double end)
{
    double integral = 0; 
    for (long double i = begin; i < end; i += _step)
    {
        integral += fn(i) * _step;  // _step defined in class 
    }
    return integral;
}
```

Currently I am calling this function from main.cpp using

```
calculus cl;
std::cout << cl.integralSimple(calculus::identity,0,1);
std::cout << cl.integralSimple([](double x) { return x*x; }, 0, 1);
```

where identity is a static function defined in calculus.h and the other uses a lambda function.

I was wondering whether I could make the syntax easier for the user and closer to a mathematics way. 
So what I would prefer is that the user just have to type:

```
std::cout << cl.integralSimple( x*x ,0,1); // Always take a function of this form 
std::cout << cl.integralSimple( x*sin(x) - x*x ,0,1);
```

Is there any way to achieve this in C++?

Comment: Boost's Lambda and Phoenix libraries sort of do that, but really, the lambdas only wrap the expression; they don't interfere with it.

Comment: I didn't change `intergalSimple` to `integralSimple`, but you probably should  (five times, if I count correctly).

Comment: I understand the desire to use Mathematical language(s) in programming. But we do need to accept programming languages and Mathematical language are different, like English and Chinese and Japanese. We do need to accept expressing the same meanings in less familiar forms.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Changed them. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/lambda/s03.html) was designed for. The syntax would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>

const double PI  =3.141592653589793238463;

double func(double v) { return std::sin(v); } // to avoid having to
                                              // cast std::sin

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;

    std::vector<double> v = {0, PI / 4, PI / 2, PI};

    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
        std::cout << _1 * bind(func, _1) - _1 * _1 << '\n'
    //                    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
    //                    to delay invocation of func
    );
}
```

Whether that's *better* than the C++11 lambda syntax or not is entirely up to you.

Note that thanks to C++14 and some abuse of features, we can actually write exactly the expression you want too:

```
auto x = _1;

auto sin(decltype(_1) ) {
    return bind(static_cast<double(*)(double)>(std::sin), _1);
}
```

With that, we can do:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
    std::cout << x * sin(x) - x * x << '\n');
```

Which will print exactly the same thing the original example did. Just... more cryptically.

Comment: thank you. I will try to incorporate this into my code. If you don't mind me asking , will this syntax be possible in any other language .I plan on implementing the functions in C++ and then calling it from Python. So is there anything I can do in Python which till allow the user to simply say integrate(x*x)

Comment: @nnrales I'm sure it's possible to write such a library in Python. I do not know if it exists or not though.